# Expressing a vector as the best linear combination of "random" vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have something like:

$\vec{v} = \langle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \rangle$

and I have a set of vectors (these are all just made up numbers):

$\vec{w_1} = \langle 3, 7, -2, -4, 8 \rangle$

$\vec{w_2} = \langle 1, 2, 0, 0, -4 \rangle$

$\vec{w_3} = \langle 8, 11, -2, 3, 4 \rangle$

$\vec{w_4} = \langle -2, 4, -2, -4, 2 \rangle$

$\vec{w_5} = \langle 4, 13, 8, 1, 0 \rangle$

Let $\vec{v}' = a_1 \vec{w_1} + a_2 \vec{w_2} + a_3 \vec{w_3} + a_4 \vec{w_4} + a_5 \vec{w_5}$ where the $a_n$ are unknown coefficients.

Is there a procedure I can use to find the coefficients such that $\vec{v}'$ is as close to $\vec{v}$ as possible?  (Perhaps according to some metric like minimizing $\left|\vec{v} - \vec{v}'\right|$).

Note that the $\vec{w_n}$ are not orthogonal or normal, so they don't form a basis set.

Comment: Vectors need not be orthogonal to form a basis...

Comment: Note that you don't need vectors to be orthogonal to form a basis, independence of enough of them will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want exact equality.

$$v = a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2 + a_3 w_3 +a_4 w_4 + a_5 w_5.$$

Looking at the first element in each vector, we have

$$1 = 3a_1 + 1a_2+8a_3-2a_4+4a_5.$$

For the second element,

$$2 = 7a_1+2a_2+11a_3+4a_4+13a_5.$$

And so on. It should be immediately clear that this forms a linear system:

$$\begin{pmatrix} w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4 & w_5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\a_4 \\a_5\end{pmatrix} = v.$$

Suppose now that $v$ is not spanned by $\{w_1,\ldots,w_5\}$. Then there will be no solution to $\mathbf{a}$, but we could instead find $\mathbf{a}$ such that $\| \mathbf{W}\mathbf{a}-v\|$ is minimized ($\mathbf{W}$ is the matrix formed by the w's). But to make that sensible, we need to define a different basis on which "closeness" makes some sort of sense.

Then as Ross Millikan mentions in the comments, we can project v onto the subspace spanned by our new basis set.

Comment: In fact, what will be spanned is a subspace.  We can then project $v$ onto the subspace to minimize $\| \mathbf{W}\mathbf{a}-v\|$

Comment: @RossMillikan Indeed. I added this to the answer since it wasn't explicit :)